# What means is vim commnad ":v"or":g!" when it words on range

Tags: vim

Vim manual says

`:[range]v[global]/{pattern}/[cmd]
    Execute the Ex command [cmd] (default ":p") on thelines within [range] where {pattern} does NOT match."`

but when use command like ":v/{pattern1}/,/{pattern2}/[cmd]", the result is not what I want, and I don't understand why.

For exapler, there is a text file

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

When i execute the command ":g/2/,/4/d",then the line from "2" to "4" will be deleted.
It's fine.

But if i execute the command ":v/2/,/4/d", it's not work just like i know.

I thinkit should keep the three lines from "2" to "4", deleted others, but it not.

Or, I think the command ":v/2/,/4/d" may works like ":g/[^2]/, /[^4]/d", but it's not, too.

So, **what's the exact mean about the command ":v/{pattern1}/,/{pattern2}/[cmd]"**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the command does what it should do. I think you didn't understand the command correctly. I try to explain it.

first, the `:g` one. You have: `:g/p1/,/p2/d` we should read the command as:

```
:g/p1/   "for each line match p1
,/p2/d   "till line match p2, delete.
```

here you used a range, from line matching `p1` till (`,` comma) line matching `p2`. with your `1-5` example, vim find the 1st matched line `#2`, then you have a `2,/4/d`, so line 2-4 was removed. `:g` is not finished, it looks the rest line : the `5` line, it doesn't match `/2/`, next line, oops, hit EOF, so `:g` has done its job.

If you made an example from `1 to 20` , you would see some error msg `Pattern not found`, this happens because, the `:g` can find `/2/`, but the range ending  `/4/` could not be found any longer, it has been removed by last `d` command.  Do a test by yourself, you will see what I meant.

If `:g` is clear, `:v` is easy to understand. `:v/2/,/4/d`

vim search first line doesn't match `/2/`, it would be the first line `1`, then do `1,/4/d`, that is, line 1-4 are deleted. `:v` command is not yet finished, it goes to the line with `5`, which is line number 1 now, it doesn't match `/2/` either, so vim take it, does a `1,/4/d`, but there is no line matching `/4/` in your buffer, so `pattern not found` error message will be displayed. And `:v` command finished its job.

You should keep in mind that, `:g/{pattern}/cmd` is not `:g{range}cmd`. **pattern** and **range** are different things. do a `:h range` to see detail

That's why you got the result. Hope it is clear.

Comment: Oh, I know, the "NOT match" of the ":v" is just work on parttern 1, but not work on parttern 2.Thanks.

Comment: No, the point is you are completely misunderstanding the command syntax. There is only ONE pattern that affects the behavior of :v. The second pattern in your command is part of a range applied to the :d command. It has nothing to do with the :v command.